# ios change textview size based on data in uitableviewcell?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

My Project is based on parsing json data from webservice, and displaying in screens. now my problem, am receiving json data like this

```
needList =     (
                {
            createdBy = "Created By: u,u1";
            expDate = "Expiration Date: 27/Feb/2014";
            fulfillQuan = null;
            id = 630;
            needDesc = "prayer description";
            needFrom = need;
            needTitle = "prayer title";
            needType = Service;
            totalQuan = null;
        },
                {
            createdBy = "Created By: u,u1";
            expDate = "Expiration Date: 27/Feb/2014";
            fulfillQuan = "FulfilledQuantity: 0";
            id = 629;
            needDesc = food;
            needFrom = need;
            needTitle = "food title";
            needType = Product;
            totalQuan = "TotalQuantity:10";
        },
                {
            createdBy = "Created By: u3,u3";
            expDate = "Expiration Date: 26/Feb/2014";
            fulfillQuan = "FulfilledQuantity: 0";
            id = 640;
            needDesc = "Food Description";
            needFrom = need;
            needTitle = "Food Title";
            needType = "Food Donation";
            totalQuan = "TotalQuantity:10";
        },
                {
            createdBy = "Created By: u,u1";
            expDate = "Expiration Date: 25/Feb/2014";
            fulfillQuan = "FulfilledQuantity: 0";
            id = 635;
            needDesc = "cell phone description ,cell phone description ,cell phone description ,cell phone description ,cell phone description ,cell phone description ,cell phone description ,cell phone description ,cell phone description ,cell phone description ,cell phone description ,cell phone description ,cell phone description ,cell phone description ,cell phone description ,";
            needFrom = need;
            needTitle = "cell title blackberry, cell title blackberry,cell title blackberry,cell title blackberry,cell title blackberry,cell title blackberry,cell title blackberry,cell title blackberry,cell title blackberry,cell title blackberry,cell title blackber";
            needType = Product;
            totalQuan = "TotalQuantity:10";
        },
                {
            createdBy = "Created By: c,c31";
            expDate = "Expiration Date: 20/Feb/2014";
            fulfillQuan = "FulfilledQuantity: 0";
            id = 638;
            needDesc = null;
            needFrom = need;
            needTitle = "test money doantion";
            needType = "Money Donation";
            totalQuan = "TotalAmount :2000";
        },
                {
            createdBy = "Created By: c,c31";
            expDate = "Expiration Date: 20/Feb/2014";
            fulfillQuan = "FulfilledQuantity: 0";
            id = 639;
            needDesc = null;
            needFrom = need;
            needTitle = "need money title";
            needType = "Money Donation";
            totalQuan = "TotalAmount :55";
        }
    );
}
```

These two datas am receiving causes me a problem. `needDesc` and `needTitle`. am those datas in `textview` inside a `tableviewcell(subclassed)`. Now i need to auto resize a textview based on data am receiving. i tried it but didnt get proper solution. i have no idea on how to do it. pls help me friends. Thanks in advance
Here is the code for my tableview cell and resizing code i tried

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"Need_Request";
    NeedReqListCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.createdby.text = (NSString *)[array3 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.product.text = (NSString *)[array4 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.expiration.text = (NSString *)[array5 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.totalquantity.text = (NSString *)[array6 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.fulfilledquantity.text = (NSString *)[array7 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.titleview.text = (NSString *)[array1 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    CGRect bodyFrame = cell.titleview.frame;
    bodyFrame.size = cell.titleview.contentSize;
    [cell.titleview setFrame:bodyFrame];

    return cell;

}
```

And here is the code i tried for auto resizing But its not worked

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NeedReqListCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Need_Request"];
    float oldHeight = cell.titleview.frame.size.height;
    cell.titleview.text = (NSString *)[array1 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    CGRect bodyFrame = cell.titleview.frame;
    bodyFrame.size = cell.titleview.contentSize;
    float newHeight = cell.titleview.contentSize.height;
    return tableView.rowHeight - oldHeight + newHeight;
}
```

Comment: you will not get cell dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier  in heightForRowAtIndexPath. you calculate height manually based on text.

Comment: you may count height of text by use - (CGSize)sizeWithFont:(UIFont *)font constrainedToSize:(CGSize)size lineBreakMode:(NSLineBreakMode)lineBreakMode; And do not use tableView.rowHeight to return heightForRowAtIndexPath you need fix it with number

Answer (score 0):

Try below code..

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {

             NSString *cellText1=[array2 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];;
             UIFont *cellFont1=[UIFont fontWithName:@"SourceSansPro-Bold" size:18];
             CGSize constraintSize1=CGSizeMake(300,MAXFLOAT);
             CGSize txtViewSize1=[cellText1 sizeWithFont:cellFont1 constrainedToSize:constraintSize1 lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];

            NSString *cellText=[array1 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]; //if it returns yourtextview text
            UIFont *cellFont = [UIFont fontWithName:@"SourceSansPro-Regular" size:13.0];
            CGSize constraintSize = CGSizeMake(300.0f, MAXFLOAT);//225
            CGSize labelSize = [cellText sizeWithFont:cellFont constrainedToSize:constraintSize lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];

            return labelSize.height+txtViewSize1.height+150; //here +60 is the total height of other fields which are displayed in your custom cell
    }
```

Hope it helps..

Comment: every datas getting override on each other

Comment: you need to increase the height value (150 in my answer)..based on your requirement.then it will not overide.

Comment: also followed by this text view. another text view need to be set. with same concept of autosizing. those two textviews getting collided

Comment: You need to display textview at bottom of your custom cell(As it will increase or decrease as per text)..Make sure that array1 is retrieving the textview values..

Comment: array1 is for titleview(text view name) its working fine. Now array2 is to be set for descview without colliding with titleviewtext. how to do this friend

Comment: it working fine with small issue over here  bodyFrame.size = cell.titleview.contentSize;
    [cell.titleview setFrame:bodyFrame];
    [cell.descview setFrame:bodyFrame];
Bcoz of this both text view  falling in same place

Comment: Remove [cell.titleview setFrame:bodyFrame]; lines of code..Accept my answer(tick it) if you got the solution..

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {    
NSString *text = [self.arrTexts objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
    CGSize size;
    if (SYSTEM_VERSION_LESS_THAN(@"7.0")) {
        // code here for iOS 5.0,6.0 and so on
         CGSize fontSize = [text sizeWithFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:12]];
         size = fontSize;
    } else {
        // code here for iOS 7.0
        NSDictionary *attributesDictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                              [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:17], NSFontAttributeName,
                                              nil];
       CGRect fontSizeFor7 = [text boundingRectWithSize:CGSizeMake(605, 500)
                                           options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin
                                        attributes:attributesDictionary
                                           context:nil];
        size = fontSizeFor7.size;
    }
    return size.height +15;
}
```

Comment: every datas getting override on each other

Answer (score 0):

```
Calculate height like this:

-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {
            NSString *String=[array1 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]; 
            CGSize constraintSize = CGSizeMake(titleviewWidth, FLT_MAX);
            CGSize size = [cellText sizeWithFont:titleviewFont constrainedToSize:constraintSize lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];
            return size.height+padding; // add extra padding height
  }

Change titleview frame like this
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   .........
   .........
   /* 
CGRect bodyFrame = cell.titleview.frame;
    bodyFrame.size = cell.titleview.contentSize;
    // it not possible change titleview frame in this class
    [cell.titleview setFrame:bodyFrame];
*/
   //add method and change frame in NeedReqListCell class
   [cell changeHeight:titleviewHeight];

return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//Add Every Label like This., in cellForRowAtIndexPath method

    NSString *text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[Array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"needDesc"]];
    UIFont *font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"ArialMT" size:12];
    CGSize size = [(text ? text : @"") sizeWithFont:font constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(200, 9999) lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];
    UILabel *lbl_desc=[[UILabel alloc]init];
    lbl_desc.numberOfLines = 0;
    lbl_desc.frame=CGRectMake(70,18, size.width, size.height);
    lbl_desc.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
    lbl_desc.text = (text ? text : @"");
    lbl_desc.font = font;
    lbl_desc.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
    lbl_desc.textColor = [UIColor darkTextColor];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:lbl_desc];
    [lbl_desc release];
```

Comment: Am doing this inside a uitableviewcell. so the size of cell and label wont get collided by above code ah

Comment: can yow set cell hight progarmetically

Comment: ya Please add. Note: am subclassing uitableviewcell and diaplaying two textviews back to back with same autoresizing concept

Comment: i need to add one more textview after this.. so the height of table view wont get collided ah

Comment: you can add multiple textview like this and set hight on sixe

Comment: if we add multiple textviews in cellforrowindexpath means heightForRowAtIndexPath also will get increased ah

Comment: you add multiple textfield on cell then set multiple height.

Answer (score 0):

```
//For Height
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSString *text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[Array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"needDesc"]];
    UIFont *font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"ArialMT" size:12];
    CGSize size = [(text ? text : @"") sizeWithFont:font constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(200, 9999) lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];


    NSString *secondtext = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[Array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"needDescsecond"]];
    UIFont *secondfont = [UIFont fontWithName:@"ArialMT" size:12];
    CGSize secondsize = [(secondtext ? secondtext : @"") sizeWithFont:secondfont constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(200, 9999) lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];

    int last_size = size.height +secondsize.height + 140;

    return last_size;
}
```